# PropertyGrid не видит изменение объекта

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-basic, vb.net, propertygrid

Есть небольшой редактор объектов коллекции элементов вложенных друг в друга.
При создании элемента первого уровня, срабатывает событие
*PropertyGrid1_PropertyValueChanged* как и должно, но при изменении объекта на большую глубину вложенности, ни каких событий не возникает.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытался построить по восходящей передачу событий о том что элемент изменился, но что то запутался как это дело реализовать. Скорее всего пытаюсь создать велосипед и решить проблему можно по другому.

```
<DataContract()> _
<Serializable()> _
Public Class Element

'   Внешнее событие изменения
Public Event ChangedChildren(ByVal sender As Object)

'   Внешнее событие изменения
Public Event ChangedName(ByVal sender As Object)

' Fields
<DataMember()> _
Private _childs As List(Of Element) = New List(Of Element)

<DataMember()> _
Private _atributes As List(Of ElementAttribute) = New List(Of ElementAttribute)

' Properties
Public Property Children() As List(Of Element)
    Set(ByVal value As List(Of Element))
        _childs = value
        RaiseEvent ChangedChildren(Me)
    End Set
    Get
        Return Me._childs
    End Get
End Property

Public ReadOnly Property Atributes() As List(Of ElementAttribute)
    Get
        Return Me._atributes
    End Get
End Property

Private _name As String

Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return Me._name
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        Me._name = value
        RaiseEvent ChangedName(Me)
    End Set
End Property


Private _closed As Boolean = True

Public Property Closed() As Boolean
    Get
        Return _closed
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        _closed = value
    End Set
End Property


End Class
```

**UPDATE**

Может кто то подсказать как по восходящей поднять событие и задействовать в клиентском коде подобного класса это событие?

Comment: Ну, в принципе такое можно организовать, но довольно сложно. Расскажите лучше свою более высокоуровневую задачу, может быть, её решить будет легче.

Comment: И кстати: winforms или wpf?

Comment: я уже нашел ответ как эту задачу для грида решить, скоро оформлю ответ, сейчас тесты проведу сперва.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
public delegate void MyFormClosedEventHandler(object sender,
                                    FormClosedEventArgs e);

public static event MyFormClosedEventHandler MyFormClosed;

public MyCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type) { }
protected override CollectionForm CreateCollectionForm()
{
    CollectionForm collectionForm = base.CreateCollectionForm();
    collectionForm.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(collection_FormClosed);
    return collectionForm;
}

void collection_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    if (MyFormClosed != null)
    {
        MyFormClosed(this, e);
    }
}
}

[Editor(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]


public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    //  Make the property grid listen to collection properties changes
    MyCollectionEditor.MyFormClosed += new MyCollectionEditor.MyFormClosedEventHandler
                                        (propertyGrid_CollectionFormClosed);
}

private void propertyGrid_CollectionFormClosed(object s, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    //  Code to run when collection form is closed
}
```